# Does echo inside "if exists" always requires double quotes in windows command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, quotes

I am trying to look for existence of a file and then print out the directory as below on command prompt:

```
C:\> if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" (echo C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\)
```

This fails with following error:

```
\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.
```

If I rewrite my command as

```
C:\> if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" (echo "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\")
```

this prints:

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\"
```

I make use of the output of this command, and the quotes around it are causing some issues. Is there any way I can echo this without adding the quotes?

Comment: No quotes on the `if` statement, or no quotes at all? Because doing stuff with a path that contains spaces requires quotes, but you can use a variable if you care about aesthetics.

Comment: if statement is fine.. Im talking about just the echo. As I read the output from echo and use it somewhere else. So I have to manually strip these before I use and was wondering if it can be done in the command itself

Comment: The problem are the parentheses in the `echo` part, the closing `)` in `(x86)` is considered as the counterpart of the opening `(` in front of `echo`; so either remove the `(`/`)` around the whole `echo` command line, or escape the parentheses in `(x86)` like `^(x86^)` or `(x86^)`...

Comment: Aaah... I was assuming () was necessary to follow if exists <file>. Removing the paranthesis worked. Thanks

Comment: The parentheses are required if you want to build a multi-line block containing multiple conditional commands, or if you want to use the `else` clause; for only a single command behind `if` they are not required...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem are the parentheses in the `echo` part, the closing `)` in `(x86)` is considered as the counterpart of the opening `(` in front of `echo`.

```cmd
if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" (echo C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\)
rem //                                                                         ^                         ^
rem //                                                                         +opening-----------closing+
```

So you have two options:

1. either remove the `(`/`)` around the whole `echo` command line:

   ```cmd
   if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" echo C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
   ```
2. or escape the parentheses in `(x86)`, like:

   ```cmd
   if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" (echo C:\Program Files^(x86^)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\)
   ```

   or:

   ```cmd
   if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" (echo C:\Program Files(x86^)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\)
   ```

---

The parentheses around the conditional command part is not necessary, unless:

1. you want to build a multi-line block:

   ```cmd
   if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" (
       echo C:\Program Files^(x86^)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
   )
   ```
2. or you want to use the `else` clause:

   ```cmd
   if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" (echo C:\Program Files^(x86^)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\) else echo ERROR: file not found!
   ```
3. or a combination of the above:

   ```cmd
   if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" (
       echo C:\Program Files^(x86^)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
   ) else (
       echo ERROR: file not found!
   )
   ```

---

for more information, consult this: [`IF`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html).

Answer (score 1):

The most points are already explained by the answer of aschipfl.
But normally you cant or don't want to escape the parenthesis, as you are working with variables with *unknown* content like `%ProgramFiles%`.
When you want to echo them without quotes and without escaping you can use delayed expansion.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "dir=!ProgramFiles!"
if exist "!dir!" (
   echo !dir!
)
```

Comment: Thats an interesting solution. However, would this work if I use them as a single command seperated by '&' , for example: setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion&
set "dir=!ProgramFiles!"&
if exist "!dir!" (
   echo !dir!
)

Comment: @AshishGudla, your code works if you use it in a batch file, but it does not if you use it in `cmd` directly, because `setlocal` has no effect there; to enable delayed expansion in `cmd`, do it like this: `cmd /V /C set "dir=!ProgramFiles!" ^& if exist "!dir!" echo !dir!`